# How to control if first line is parsed in nodejs library csv-parse

Tags: node.js, parsing, csv

I've been using the [NodeCSV](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv) library, and I really like it.  One of the 4 component libraries [csv-parse](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse) will parse CSV strings, files, and streams in NodeJS.

The `columns` option [in the documentation](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/) allows me to set the column names in the configuration prior to parsing.

```
var parser = parse({columns: ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC']});
```

During parsing the library seems to conditionally skip the header row when I parse a CSV file.  If the CSV file's first row has column names, then the first row IS NOT parsed into the result.  But when I do not include a header row, then the first row IS parsed into the result.

Is the library automatically deciding to skip the row?  How can I control this behavior, and if it cannot be controlled how can I know what it will do?

Comment: They call it "autodiscover". You can pass a function to the `columns` property: http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/

Comment: "autodiscover" sounds scary to me.  I wish there was a way to turn it off, or at least learn more about the behavior.

Comment: There is the (tiny) doc and the source code but the default behaviour is handy, I wouldn't want the first line of data to be the columns name. But depending on the files you're parsing, you could write your own parser more or less easily.